# findFragmentByTag() don't find my fragment even if I know it exist

Tags: android, android-fragments

I write this condition :

```
 if(activity.getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()!=0 &&
 activity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("detail") != null && compteur==0){
```

and I know the app should enter in the block behind this condition because I used the debug tool of Eclipse and I navigate through the variables to find my backStack in my activity and the Array that contains the fragments of the BackStack show this :

```
 [BackStackEntry{53954aa4 #0 detail}, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
```

So my app should enter in the block but instead not ... And I setting up all I can do to verify the state of the array at the moment of the app verify his content : It's exactly the state I write above

Is the findFragmentByTag() do exactly what we can think of this function name ? Or it do something different I didn't imagine ?

EDIT :

The fragment which is in the array above comes from this code :

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.layOffers, newOffer, "detail");
transaction.addToBackStack("detail");
transaction.commit();
```

Trying with this doesn't change anything :

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.layOffers, newOffer, "detail");
transaction.addToBackStack("detail");
transaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you haven't mentioned tag in replace method So,
Use this structure of replace method of fragment

```
replace(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, String tag)

ft.replace(R.id.container, newFragment,"detail");
```

Comment: I do this anytime I should do it and in the content of the array, it show that my "detail" tag is present for my fragment in the BackStack so the problem should not be that.

Comment: I can't post all code but I have edit what should be necessary :)